# Skip Iteration in std::for_each on specific condition

Tags: c++

I'm working on a program that needs to iterate over a range.
I wish to know if I can use `continue` like when I use in range based for loop.

Working :

```
std::vector<std::string> v = {"foo", "bar", "baz", "foobar"};
for (auto s : v)
{
    if (*s.front() == 'b')
        continue;
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Not-Working :

```
std::vector<std::string> v = {"foo", "bar", "baz", "foobar"};
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const std::string& s) {
    if (*s.front() == 'b')
        continue;
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
});
```

Comment: `continue` is a reserved word and can be used only inside loop. In second example you are using `continue` inside function.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Replace `continue` with `return`.